# Show image preview when click back button from browser

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image, file-upload

I am currently using a file upload plugin which can show preview of uploaded image from [Jasny file input](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript/#fileinput).

After I submit my form, images were uploaded to my server, then I click back button on my web browser, the image previews did not show up anymore but values from other text input were still there. I know those images are still in tmp location because when I click submit form again those same images were uploaded to my server again.

So is there anyway to show image preview after clicking back button from browser?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you have to go "back"? Instead of having a user go "back" (which I would consider bad practice), generate and output the form, along with any contents including the image, to the browser.

Comment: This is a good answer. This is a so called "Good Practice!"

Comment: What a helpless answer! The problem is the back button from the browser, How can i stop user from clicking back? And IF they click it, what do you consider "good pratice" in this case?

Comment: Expire the form immediately on load, or try a different method of sending data. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580085/show-webpage-has-expired-on-back-button

Comment: I have found solution for this. I will need to clear form value when user clicks back button from browser: <body onLoad="document.MyForm.reset();">

Comment: I think you're taking the wrong direction on this. but best of luck to you.