# Optimal way of form submitting compatible with back button in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, forms, file-upload, back

I have seen form submission to evolve through years. My question is, what is the optimal strategy to follow for a form submission in PHP which is compatible with back button? I think that the ideal behaviour should be this:

1. Submission to the same URL. If I am in *www.example.com/contact*, I would expect to be sent to the same URL after submission, unless I am logging, in which case I am redirected.
2. If I hit the browser's back button, I would not have to get the classical "Form expired" message. Ideally, a custom error message indicating that I am not allowed to re-send the form should display.
3. PHP form validation, with a custom message (PHP-generated) with the form fields in error.
4. Compatibility with file uploading, by sending first the file via AJAX. In that way, I can upload any file first, store it, and if the submission is succesful, reuse the file without need of the user sending it again after form correction.

I have read technical books in which the strategy of Javascript validation prior to sending the form is priviledged among the server validation, with the caution that if I do not do that, I will not be able to re-fill the form. That surprised me a lot...

```
<input type="text" name="surname" id="surname"
 value="<?php if(!empty($_POST['surname'])
print html_entity_decode($_POST['surname']); ?>" />
```

... so after trying dozens of form submission types, I am seeking advice about the best form nowdays (modern browsers, HTML5, ...)

Comment: Why not do the entire form using AJAX? Then there will be no problem with hitting the back button and you can just use javascript/jquery to show a success or fail notice.

Comment: For "classic" forms (no AJAX), the generally accepted "standard" to avoid said message in the browser is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: Yes, I was directed almost naturally to that solution, doing all the validation and all that in server, but what about several steps forms? And what happens if Javascript is switched off (even if that is not default behaviour in modern browsers). Somehow I am trapped in many different solutions, and after several years, I feel that I do not do it well in no one of them.

Comment: this is "googlable" depends on what type of web server you use...see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580085/show-webpage-has-expired-on-back-button for ideas

Comment: For the PRG solution, maybe I don't understand well, but don't see how I can get the form re-filled with the correct value sent if I am using a GET solution, I am allowed to use GET parameters so I would use $_REQUEST in the PHP to fill again the values ?

Comment: I saw the solution of point 2 in a tickets web, but I don't know how they achieve the effect, seems the most efficient way, IMHO.