# How to set the document expired error message when the user has clicked the back button?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have written a chat application using `html,php and jquery`.In that if I have logged in to the page then, I have pressed the log out ,it will redirect to the logout.php file in that php script, I have changed the value of the session and cookies.

If I have clicked the back button in the firefox it has been taking to the previous page.

> `Question:-`
>   How to avoid the loading the previous page if the user has clicked the backward button and also to show the error message that document has expired ?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [show "webpage has expired" on back button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580085/show-webpage-has-expired-on-back-button)